# Draw in a fragment

Tags: android

I want to add my own graphics in a fragment.
Is it possible to add for example a circle in the fragment?
I have this code:

```
public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment  {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
    public static final String ARG_OBJECT = "object";
    public static final String ARG_DATA = "data";


    public DummySectionFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Bundle args = getArguments();
        int position = args.getInt(ARG_OBJECT);
        String data=args.getString(ARG_DATA);
        int tabLayout = 0;
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
        tabLayout = R.layout.fragment_company_products;
        break;
        case 1:
        tabLayout = R.layout.fragment_main_dummy;
        break;
        case 2:
        tabLayout = R.layout.fragment_main_dummy;
        break;
        case 3:
            tabLayout = R.layout.fragment_main_dummy;
        break;
        }

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(tabLayout, container, false);

        TextView dummyTextView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);

        //dummyTextView.setText(args.getInt(ARG_OBJECT)+"\n"+data+"asd");
        return rootView;
    }


}
```

I asked this because i want to change on each fragment my graphics, and on some of those fragments I should add some 2d graphics like circle or arc or rectangle.
Is this possible?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to add `View` subclass to your `Fragment`'s layout and do custom drawing in `onDraw`.

Comment: Do you know how I can select that custom view?

Comment: Fragments inflate normal layouts.  Just put your custom view in the layout that the fragment inflates...